# Importing initialized object from the same directory stay None - Python

Tags: python, import, module, package

I have the following directory

```
dir1\
    ..\main.py
    ..\file2.py
```

in main.py i have the following code

```
import myObj
obj1 = None
def func1():
   global obj1
   obj1 = myObj.myObj()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    func1()

import file2.py
```

in file2.py:

```
from main.py import obj1
```

but obj1 is None , any idea why ?

**Update: Changing the question to this :**
I have the following directory

```
dir1\
    ..\main.py
    ..\file2.py
    ..\file3.py
```

in main.py i have the following code

```
import file2

def func1():
    file2.init_func()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func1()
```

in file2.py :

```
import myObj
obj1=None
def init_func():
    global myobj
    obj1= myObj.myObj()
```

in file3.py:

```
from file2 import obj1
```

But obj1 is None in file3,Why it is not initialized?

Comment: Because in line 2 of main.py, obj1 is declared as None. The code protected by 'if __name__ == "__main__"' is not executed when you import the file from another file. What you need to do in file2.py is to import func1() from main.py, and then execute func1 in file2.py.

Comment: Or better, avoid using globals this way...

Comment: @Kefeng91 what about now ?